# TAB key in Java Applets

Tags: java, applet

I'm seeing two problems with Java code which expects user to press TAB key, when the code is running as an applet

Firstly in Chrome, the press is seemingly not being detected.

More nastily in IE9 pressing TAB loses focus on the applet altogether.

I've seen these reported before but my searching so far didn't suggest a neat solution, or even a quick answer if a solution exists... does it?

Running as a desktop or WebStart/JNLP app TAB works well, only in applets does it get messy.

Comment: refer the java bug http://bugs.sun.com/bugdatabase/view_bug.do?bug_id=6456655

Comment: What is your question here? Whether we can confirm the behaviour, have a workaround, a bugfix, a suggestion which key to use instead?

Comment: @userunknown "searching so far didn't suggest a neat solution, or even a quick answer if a solution exists"

Comment: A quick answer to which question?

Answer (score 3):

I know it’s late to reply this Question but still if anybody else face the same issue 
then hope this will help.
below link solve my issue.
http://dogfeathers.com/mark/java7issue.html

Answer (score 0):

```
 public void init()
  {
      Container topParent = null;
      Container parent = this;
      // The natural thing would be to call getParent() until it returns
      //   null, but then you would be looping for a long time, since
      //   PluginEmbeddedFrame's getParent() returns itself.
      for (int k=0; k < 10; k++) {
          topParent = parent;
          parent = parent.getParent();
          if (parent == null) break;
      }

      // If topParent isn't a KeyEventDispatcher then we must be in some
      //   Plugin version that doesn't need the workaround.
      try {
          KeyEventDispatcher ked = (KeyEventDispatcher)topParent;
          KeyboardFocusManager kfm = KeyboardFocusManager.getCurrentKeyboardFocusManager();
          // You have to remove it twice, otherwise the problem isn't fixed
          kfm.removeKeyEventDispatcher(ked);
          kfm.removeKeyEventDispatcher(ked);
      } catch (ClassCastException e) {}
    }
```

Comment: A little comment in your answer outside the codebox would help to understand the concept behind the code. And what question the code is the answer for.